# Dart Polymer 1 - How to detect changes to <content> nested components

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0

Given custom component A:

```
<dom-module id="my-a-component">
  <template>
    <content id="nestednodes"></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Then:

```
<my-a-component>
  <my-b-component label='{{blabel}}'></my-b-component>
</my-a-component>
```

How can I get updated inside "my-a-component" when any children under "#nestednodes" is updated? or, when a new component gets added to the `<content>`?

I've been toying with MutationObserver but can't seem to see any updates to those nodes. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind posting the `MutationObserver` code you tried? I think that's the way to go. I'm sure it's working and I don't know anything else that would be a good fit.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you, I ended up just using:
`<content select>` with multiple selection parameters. This works since I can change both "A/B" components, and the content selectors allows me to specify multiple selectors. 
`<content select="my-b-component[label='first'][label='last']"></content>`